# Python unified diff with line numbers from both "files"

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I'm trying to figure out a way to create unified diffs with line numbers only showing `N` lines of context. I have been unable to do this with `difflib.unified_diff`. I need to show changes in both files.

The closest I can come is using `diff` on the command line like so:

`/usr/bin/diff 
    --unchanged-line-format=' %.2dn %L' 
    --old-line-format="-%.2dn %L" 
    --new-line-format="+%.2dn %L" 
    file1.py
    file2.py`

**BUT** I only want to show `N` lines of context, and `/usr/bin/diff` doesn't seem to support context with a custom line format (eg. -U2 is not compatible with --line-format "`conflicting output style options`").

Below is an example of what I'd like to accomplish (the same output as the above diff, but only showing 1 line of context surrounding changes):

`+01: def renamed_function()
-01: def original_function():
 02: 
+03:    """ Neat stuff here """
 04: 
 21: 
+22: # Here's a new comment
 23:
 85: # Output the value of foo()
+86: print "Foo is %s"%(foo())
-86: print foo()
 87:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out something very close to what I wanted to do. It's slower than regular diff, though. Here's the entire code, from my project [GitGate](https://github.com/webgovernor/gitgate).

```
def unified_diff(to_file_path, from_file_path, context=1):

    """ Returns a list of differences between two files based
    on some context. This is probably over-complicated. """

    pat_diff = re.compile(r'@@ (.[0-9]+\,[0-9]+) (.[0-9]+,[0-9]+) @@')

    from_lines = []
    if os.path.exists(from_file_path):
        from_fh = open(from_file_path,'r')
        from_lines = from_fh.readlines()
        from_fh.close()

    to_lines = []
    if os.path.exists(to_file_path):
        to_fh = open(to_file_path,'r')
        to_lines = to_fh.readlines()
        to_fh.close()

    diff_lines = []

    lines = difflib.unified_diff(to_lines, from_lines, n=context)
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('--') or line.startswith('++'):
            continue

        m = pat_diff.match(line)
        if m:
            left = m.group(1)
            right = m.group(2)
            lstart = left.split(',')[0][1:]
            rstart = right.split(',')[0][1:]
            diff_lines.append("@@ %s %s @@\n"%(left, right))
            to_lnum = int(lstart)
            from_lnum = int(rstart)
            continue

        code = line[0]

        lnum = from_lnum
        if code == '-':
            lnum = to_lnum
        diff_lines.append("%s%.4d: %s"%(code, lnum, line[1:]))

        if code == '-':
            to_lnum += 1
        elif code == '+':
            from_lnum += 1
        else:
            to_lnum += 1
            from_lnum += 1

    return diff_lines
```

Comment: Instead of reading in different files how can we pipe in diff of git diff whether `HEAD^ HEAD` or different head location ?